# How to Add Click event in Stack Layout or Frame

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin.forms please help me out how i can add click event in Stack Layout or Frame

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Grid.Row="0" HasShadow="true" OutlineColor = "Black">
</Frame>


<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#313FA0" Grid.Row="0">
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can add a TapGestureRecognizer to the StackLayout in XAML like this:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#313FA0">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

Then you can implement the **OnTapped** method in the code behind:

```
void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using the MVVM pattern and would like to Bind the tap to an ICommand in the ViewModel, that can be achieved like this:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#313FA0">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

In your ViewModel you would have:

```
private ICommand _tapCommand;
pubic ICommand TapCommand => (_tapCommand ?? _tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped));

void OnTapped() 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

There are some really good guides on the Xamarin website:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/gestures/#Using_Xaml

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/

Comment: How would you do this within a custom render

Answer (score 13):

Well, thanks @**pnavk** , according to what i saw, allow me also to share this, the Views *(Layouts,Frame,Images etc)* which do not have the inbuilt OnClick or Click Events have the same way of tackling the click Event.

**As follows :**

**For an Image:**

```
<Image>
   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onImageCitizenReporterTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**For a Frame :**

```
<Frame>
   <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onFrameCitizenReporterTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

**For StackLayout :**

```
<StackLayout>
   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onStackCitizenReporterTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout >
```

**Cheers.**

Answer (score 0):

Sincere thanks to Xamarin Certified Developer **Udara Alvis** for this solution which is the best because it achieves both goals: exact image and text positionning and the click event, no tap gesture and no bad content layout when button is very large.

[The link to the solution of button with exact text and image positionning](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/xfhacks-005-button-with-full-control-on-text-and-icon/)

Code sample:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" IsClippedToBounds="True" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!--  Button Control  -->
<Button Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppMainColor}" Clicked="GoToLoginPage" CornerRadius="20"/>

<StackLayout InputTransparent="True" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">

<!--  Text Label  -->
<Label Text="Se déconnecter" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="20" TextColor="White"
HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

<!--  Icon Image  -->
<Image HorizontalOptions="End" Source="log_out.png" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

</StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

[ScreenShot of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX00O.png)